# My code doesn't fetch data until after a re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So i have been trying to fetch data from an API and the link was dependent on a url parameter, but the data is fetched only after a re-render and i cant access them in my render function.

It works on normal pages but when i try to fetch data inside a route depending on a parameter passed with that route, it doesnt work. How could i solve this problem?

NOTE: my fetch is inside a different component with a different file from the one im passing the parameter with

```
  const { name } = useParams();
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`);
    setCountries(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Its normal behavior as you and sending an async call to fetch data, and at that time 1st render is called,
To handle this you should add a new state called loading and set it true before calling API and set it false once you got data,
and on bases on loading state, show some loader in ur render method

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out.

Comment: so you want to fire the API call before rendering ? . I don't think its possible atleast with useEffect , because useEffect will be called only after the component is rendered . The suggestion provided by @sabir is a normal practice which we follow when firing the API call .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should set dependencies array in your useEffect, so for now, you've set it as empty [], and it means that it will execute only the first render. So, as I understood, you wanna execute ur fetchData function every 'name' params update, so you need to add that param to ur useEffect function, this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [name]);
```

Hope I've understood ur request correctly.

Comment: I have already tried this and it wouldn't work, having a name dependency doesn't do anything because this component gets passed a name parameter every time I click on an item in my list

Comment: So ok, guess I just don't understand what's exactly is a problem. Can you clarify, when you want to fetch data ? And how it's works now

Comment: I have 2 function components, the first component renders a list of clickable elements, and when clicked they route to a details page of that specific item, in this case the second function component. that second component is basically a placeholder for whichever item is clicked. Also when clicking on an item I pass the name of that specific item and based on it I would fetch the data from the API.   EDIT: Im using react-router-dom for routing from the first component to the second

Comment: Actually never mind, there was a simple error, I was getting that data in an array and i forgot to add the index before accessing them, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying access the fetched data before specifying the index and I didn't use map.

Comment: I'd edit out the self-deprecation part in your answer ;)